# Pausing carousel sliding when scroll position of the window is past a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I'm trying to get my bootstrap carousel to pause automatically switching slides when the user scrolls down. I am using the scrollTop() function to get a value of the scroll, but it's not pausing when I change the carousel interval to false.

Here's the script code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition > 5) {
        $('#Carousel').carousel({
            interval: false
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#Carousel').carousel({
            interval: true
        });
    }
});
```

In addition, here's the carousel defined in the HTML:

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval = "2000">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: untested!

```js
var $carousel = $('#Carousel').carousel();

$carousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  if(CURRENT_INDEX >= 5) {
    $carousel.carousel('pause');
  }
});
```

Not sure where you get your *CURRENT_INDEX* from, but I'm sure you'll figure it out :)